# Array indexing triggers repeated evaluation of the element?

Tags: haskell

I am writing a program to generate first k numbers of the form

[image],

where *a* and *b* are non-negative integers.

The algorithm I am using exploits the fact that every number in this series is generated from adding either 1 or sqrt(2) to a previous number in the series, with the series starting at 0. We'll collect the numbers in the series in an array where each element is expected to be evaluated lazily on demand. The first number in the series is 0 so we'll initialize the first element of the array with 0. We'll maintain two pointers *i* and *j* both starting at index 0 (first number in the series). The next number in the series is *min(A[i]+1, A[j]+sqrt(2))*. If the next number in the series comes from pointer *i* then pointer *i* will be incremented (as we never want to add 
1 to A[i] again) and similarly if the next number in the series comes from pointer *j* then *j* will be incremented to point to next index i.e *j+1*. Both *i* and *j* will be incremented if *A[i] + 1 = A[j] + sqrt(2)*.

I think the snippet below captures the above algorithm, however, upon running the code in ghci, it looks like function `f` is being called repeatedly with parameters 1 0 0 and the program never finishes. I don't understand how this call is being made although it seems like the call is being triggered by `v A.! i`.

```
import qualified Data.Array as A 
import Debug.Trace 

compute :: Int -> Int -> Double
compute x y = (fromIntegral x) + (fromIntegral y) * (sqrt 2)

firstK :: Int -> [(Int,Int)]
firstK k = A.elems v where 
    v = A.listArray (0,k-1) $ (0,0):f 1 0 0
    f c i j 
        | c == k = [] 
        | otherwise = traceShow (c,i,j) $
            let (ix,iy) = v A.! i 
                (jx,jy) = v A.! j 
                iv      = compute (ix+1) iy 
                jv      = compute jx (jy+1)
            in  if iv < jv 
                    then (ix+1,iy):f (c+1) (i+1) j 
                else if iv > jv 
                    then (jx,jy+1):f (c+1) i (j+1)
                    else (ix+1,iy):f (c+1) (i+1) (j+1)
```

Output -

```
λ> firstK 50
(1,0,0)
(1,0,0)
(1,0,0)
(1,0,0)
(1,0,0)
(1,0,0)
(1,0,0)
(1,0,0)
(1,0,0)
(1,0,0)
(1,0,0)
(1,0,0)
(1,0,0)
(1,0,0)
...
...
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `(i,j):f` ? I feel that if you demangled your code into separate functions, it would be easer to understand, test and debug. I'd try to define a separate function for "f", and a separate function for the generator step inside f. The problem might be that you are referring to "v" inside the definition of "v", which makes a loop. Actually you don't need "A[i]" as an array to solve the problem, because you only need 2 top values A[i] and A[j] and i/j are always going forward.

Comment: If you change it all into a list instead of array, then the code works. I think the recursive definition isn't playing well with the array-ness somehow. I also agree with @battlmonstr that this is a slightly messy implementation.

Comment: @ATayler If I use list instead of array then I'll have to use `++` function to append the new item at the end of the list. Keeping the list in reverse to get rid of `++` will make going forward infeasible.

Comment: @Kakaji that didn't seem to be the case, I modified it to get rid of arrays without needing `(++)` anywhere, not sure what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `arrayList` forces all the spine of the list too early, before the array is actually built. That makes the recursion loop forever.

We can, however, fix that using a helper function as follows.

```
-- A spine-lazy version of arrayList
arrayListLazy :: (Int, Int) -> [a] -> A.Array Int a
arrayListLazy (lo,hi) xs = A.array (lo,hi) $ go lo xs
   where
   go i _ | i > hi = []
   go i ~(e:ys) = (i, e) : go (succ i) ys

firstK :: Int -> [(Int,Int)]
firstK k = A.elems v where 
    v = arrayListLazy (0,k-1) $ (0,0):f 1 0 0
    f c i j 
        | c == k = [] 
        | otherwise = traceShow (c,i,j) $
            let (ix,iy) = v A.! i 
                (jx,jy) = v A.! j 
                iv      = compute (ix+1) iy 
                jv      = compute jx (jy+1)
            in  if iv < jv 
                    then (ix+1,iy):f (c+1) (i+1) j 
                else if iv > jv 
                    then (jx,jy+1):f (c+1) i (j+1)
                    else (ix+1,iy):f (c+1) (i+1) (j+1)
```

Small test:

```
> firstK 10
[(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(2,0),(1,1),(0,2),(3,0),(2,1),(1,2),(4,0)]
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about this `~` pattern matching. Did a reading on the same.

Comment: @Kakaji You could avoid lazy patterns and use `head` and `tail` instead. Usually they are a bad idea, but here we can't really avoid some "partial" code. Also note that `arrayListLazy` has to assume that the input list is long enough to cover all the indices between the bounds.

Comment: I just checked that using `head` and `tail` can be used to get rid of lazy pattern matching as you said. Adding my own versions of `head` and `tail` without using lazy pattern matching in their implementations also does the trick. Do you know why delegating pattern matching to separate functions "simulates" lazy pattern matching?

Comment: @Kakaji Matching against a constructor like `:` in `(e:ys)` forces the argument to be evaluated at that time. Matching against a variable `xs` does not evaluate anything, and `tail xs` will only force `xs` when it's actually needed (like lazy pattern matching).

Answer (score 4):

chi's answer discusses in detail the exact problem with your code, and the fix that would let you keep your implementation idea but get the answer you're hoping for. But I think it's also interesting to see how a native Haskell speaker would approach the same algorithm: I'm going to just use native lists, and instead of a pointer into an array I'll use the list's pointers themselves to track where we are. It looks like this:

```
vs :: [(Int,Int)]
vs = (0,0) : merge [(a+1, b) | (a, b) <- vs] [(a, b+1) | (a, b) <- vs] where
    compute (a,b) = fromIntegral a + fromIntegral b * sqrt 2
    merge xs@(xh:xt) ys@(yh:yt) = case compare (compute xh) (compute yh) of
        LT -> xh:merge xt ys
        EQ -> xh:merge xt yt
        GT -> yh:merge xs yt
```

In the recursive call to `merge`, using `xt` (instead of `xs`) is akin to incrementing your `i` pointer; using `yt` (instead of `ys`) is akin to incrementing your `j` pointer.

One nice thing about `vs` is that you don't have to declare ahead of time how many pairs you want -- you just get a lazy infinite list of them (up to rounding issues with using `Double` for `compute` of course!). The code is also significantly shorter. Here's an example run in ghci:

```
> take 10 vs
[(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(2,0),(1,1),(0,2),(3,0),(2,1),(1,2),(4,0)]
```

Comment: Very beautiful! Thank you for this!!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach using the same idea,

```
firstK k = take k $ l
  where l = (0,0) : unfoldr (\(i,j) -> Just $ case compare (uncurry compute $ first (1+) $ l!!i) (uncurry compute $ second (1+) $ l!!j) of
          LT -> (first (1+) $ l!!i, (i+1,j))
          EQ -> (first (1+) $ l!!i, (i+1,j+1))
          GT -> (second (1+) $ l!!j, (i,j+1))) (0,0)
```

Not especially tidy, but you can see where it's going In particular, the pattern matching `case compare _ _ of ...` is imo better than `if a > b else if a < b else ..`.

EDIT: Albeit worse time-complexity.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your snippet and introducing me to `unfoldr` and `uncurry` functions. I agree that pattern matching looks prettier than if/else branches. Please correct me if I am wrong but it appears to me that `!!` has a time complexity of O(n) making the overall complexity O(k^2). I was looking for an O(k) solution.

Comment: Yup, there is that :( I'll make that clear in the answer.